# Migrating OS 14 from External APFS drive to internal Sata HD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, migration

External drive is the system boot drive. Although I have attempted to restore the SATA drive from the external drive and the time machine backup, the internal HD only contains a textedit file titled "containertoinvert".
How can I reinstall system files to internal SATA drive and make it the boot disk?